# What's the next number and why?

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

What's the next number and why?

> 1,602,817,493,294,902

Comment: I DV because this "puzzle" (while interesting trick-question) is very much dependent on country-specific writing style (according to accepted answer.) Nice "gimmick". Bad puzzle.

Comment: @BmyGuest This could be corrected with a small back story specifying the nationality of the speaker.. Such as "My eccentric British Maths teacher always has a fiendish puzzle on the side of the blackboard at the beginning of class and anyone answering the puzzle is exempt from the day's homework. I want to see the new Vin Petrol film,  'Quick and Angry 7' tonight and today's puzzle is as below. How can I escape the homework?"

Comment: @Arth, duly noted, I will remember this for my next riddle

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The next number is:

> 1,602,817,493,294,903 because the original 'sequence' is just one number (1,602,817,493,294,902)

The pattern:

> With one positive integer and no additional information, the next number could be interpreted as the last plus one as in the sequence 1,2,3,4,..., n. For example, ask a person what the next number after 3 is and most people will guess 4 in the absence of any other information.

Comment: hahaha.....That was so fast, I thought it will take at least two+ hours, was it this obvious?

Comment: @smitri, the tags helped! Although one has been removed now.. I also work with databases, so get used to seeing large numbers :) Starting with a 1 also seems to make the answer jump out a bit more!

Answer (score 5):

The next number is 1,602,817,493,294,903 since the comma ',' is,in many countries, accepted as a thousands separator. If you meant 1,602,817,493,294,902 as a sequence, you may want to specify 'the next number *in this sequence*', although it seems as though you meant it as a joke/trick question.

Comment: You know, I Live in the USA, and the first thing i did was use the Commas to split  it into 6 different numbers, despite the fact that the USA Also uses Commas as thousands separators.

Comment: Although not from Australia, I use their system: Spaces as separators, full stops as decimal points.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about 'sequence', I added 'trick' tag, but I think I approved the edit mistakenly, which removed the tag

Comment: I think removing the tag may have been the best thing, since it would have alerted others that something was up.